# How to get this popup window to front?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, use-state

I am a newbie in React. I created the movie app project using React. and then I have created some additional styling for this project. I want to add a popup window for this project. I wrote some code for this component. But this popup component appears in the back of my `Movielist` component. How to get this popup window to the front?

**Here is my App.js code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import MovieList from "./components/MovieList"

const featured_api =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?`api_key=b23a3ea528a2edc9d8e8d585a98023e&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1"`

const search_api =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=b23a3ea528a2edc9d8e8d585a98023e&query="

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies(featured_api)
  }, [])

  const getMovies = (api) => {
    fetch(api)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setMovies(data.results)
      })
  }

  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (search) {
      getMovies(search_api + search)
      setSearch("")
    }
  }

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
          <input
            className="search"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            value={search}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
          />
        </form>
      </header>
      <div className="movie_container">
        {movies.length > 0 &&
          movies.map((movie) => <MovieList key={movie.id} {...movie} />)}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Here is my MovieList component**

```
import React from "react"
import Window from "./Window"

const img_api = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"

const MovieList = ({
  title,
  poster_path,
  overview,
  vote_average,
  release_date,
}) => (
  <section className="interface">
    <img
      src={
        poster_path
          ? img_api + poster_path
          : "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3693701/pexels-photo-3693701.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-olenka-sergienko-3693701.jpg&fm=jpg"
      }
      alt={title}
    />
    <div className="title">
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <p>{release_date}</p>
    </div>
    <Window />
  </section>
)

export default MovieList
```

**Here is my Popup.js component**

```
import React from "react"

const Popup = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="popup-box">
      <div className="box">
        <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>
          x
        </span>
        {props.content}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Popup
```

**Here is my Window.js component**

```
import React, { useState as uState } from "react"
import Popup from "./Popup"

function Window({ title, overview, vote_average }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = uState(false)

  const togglePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="btn"
        type="button"
        value="Read More"
        onClick={togglePopup}
      />
      {isOpen && (
        <Popup
          content={
            <>
              <b>{title}</b>
              <p>Some text</p>
            </>
          }
          handleClose={togglePopup}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Window
```

**CSS file**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #222831;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #393e46;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.search {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #222831;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.movie_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.interface {
  background-color: #393e46;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
}

.interface img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.712);
  color: #222831;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 39px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.interface:hover .title {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

@keyframes bounce {
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-6px);
  }
}

.popup-box {
  position: fixed;
  background: #00000050;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 70vh;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 85vh - 20px);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: auto;
}

.close-icon {
  content: "x";
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  right: calc(15% - 30px);
  top: calc(100vh - 85vh - 33px);
  background: #393e46;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[image: Here is my project output]

Comment: its because its also same part of dom. You need to do via css to show in front of list. js part is correct. Or you can use any css library `reactstrap` or `materialui` for popup

Comment: hey welcome to SO :) ...you can add a code sand box link for the working example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: Use portals.https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: You should add  <div className="popup-box" style={{z-index:99999}}> in place of  <div className="popup-box">

Comment: or, even better, don't write your own modal: almost any basic functionality you need at this point is a solved problem with off the shelf components like react-modal already written, with the kinks worked out for so long now that we're many major versions in at this point.

Comment: also, share your CSS styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really related to react. Use css z-index to bring an element out to the front. You should change the div with className="popup-box" to a z-index of 1000 or something